# If month is not current month

Tags: javascript

We have a .NET web service which returns JSON, including a date in string format as follows: 2012-04-30T00:00:00+12:00.

In javascript, I want to exclude dates where the month is not the current month. Hence, with the above date, the month is 04 (April) and the current month is May (in New Zealand anyway). So, I want to ignore this record, e.g, in pseudocode:

```
if(vMonth == CurrentMonth){
     dothis();
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It's pseudocode to kick you off in the right direction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: See Rob G's answer below for the solution that works in all browsers.

```
var dateOne = new Date("2012-04-30T00:00:00+12:00");​​​
var dateTwo = new Date();

if(dateOne.getMonth() == dateTwo.getMonth()) {
    alert("equal");
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mq5Tf/

More info on the date object:
MSDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
ES5: http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.2

Comment: Good enough for me:-) Thanks guys

Comment: Do not trust date conversion from string to date object. Even though ES5 specifies support for ISO8601, it will fail in IE 8 and lower at least. Manually parse the date.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. *blushes* I did not know that. Does that mean we can never trust a date object parsed from a string, or just ISO8601? I'm afraid I've used this several times over the last year or so.

Comment: You shouldn't trust host parsing at all. Note that the example uses a timezone offset of +12:00, which is [explicitly not supported by ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) (it only supports Z or UTC) and is implementation dependent. Note that 2012-04-30T20:00:00+12:00 will be 1 May.

Answer (score 3):

```
var date = new Date();
var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
var yourMonth = 4;
if(yourMonth == currentMonth ){
    /* Do this */
    alert('Hello');
}
```

Comment: haha, aw thanks. I'm always worried about posting answers here because I figure by the time i finish someone else will have done a better or faster job. Sometimes, I can type fast enough :P

Comment: Keep in mind that months are `0` based. `getMonth()` will return `3` for April.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that doesn't depend on parsing the date string:

```
function checkMonth(ds) {
  var now = new Date();
  var m = now.getMonth() + 1;
  return !!ds.match(now.getFullYear() + '-' + (m<10?'0':'') + m);
}

// on 2012-05-01
alert( checkMonth('2012-04-30T00:00:00+12:00') ); // false
alert( checkMonth('2012-05-01T00:00:00+12:00') ); // false
```

#### Edit

Note that checking the month number only works where the timezone offset should be ignored or is not significant. While `2012-04-30T00:00:00+12:00` is in April, `2012-04-30T14:00:00+12:00` will be 2am on 1 May local time.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Means April 30, months are indexes in JS
var input = new Date(2012, 03, 30);​​​
// or use format new date("2012-04-30T00:00:00+12:00") suggested in other answer

var currentDate = new Date();

if(input.getFullYear() == currentDate.getFullYear() // if you care about year
   && input.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth()) {

    // act accordingly
}
```